# FirebaseApp.configure()' could not find a valid GoogleService-info.plist

Tags: firebase

how to solve this problem,

FirebaseApp.configure()` could not find a valid GoogleService-Info.plist in your project. Please download one from [https://console.firebase.google.com/."](https://console.firebase.google.com/.%22)

how do i solve this problem